# Android - How to convert code Activity a code Fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I had problems running my activities into fragments. I searched for several ways of how to do this, but even so I am confused.

I know, it's a lot of code. I hope you can help me.

Shows what I need, but when executing an action of the button, it gives the following error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ..TaskFragment.onActivityCreated(TaskFragment.java:29)
        at ..TaskFragment.onCreateView(TaskFragment.java:37)
```

Activity class.. it works

```
 public class TaskActivity extends Activity {


TareaAdapter adapter;
ListView lvTask;
ArrayList<Task> listTask;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tareas);
    lvTask =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvTareas);
    lvTask.setDividerHeight(1);
    listTask =new ArrayList<Task>();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    if(listTask.size()==0){
        populateList();
    }
    super.onResume();
}

public Task getTask(int level, int haschild){
    Task task =new Task();
    task.nombre ="Nombre Tarea";
    task.isAbierto =false;
    task.nivel =level;
    task.tieneHijo = haschild;
    return task;
}
public void populateList()
{
    try
    {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            listTask.add(getTask(0, 1));
        }
        adapter = new TareaAdapter(TaskActivity.this, listTask);
        lvTask.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
public void CellButtonClick(View v){
    try{
        Button b=(Button)v;
        int index;
        index=(Integer) b.getTag();

        if(b.getText().toString().equals("+")){
            b.setText("-");
            Task temp[]=new Task[2];
            int PLevel= listTask.get(index).nivel +1;
            for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                temp[i]= getTask(PLevel, 1);
            }
            listTask.get(index).isAbierto =true;
            if(temp!=null){
                int addindex=index+1;
                for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
                    listTask.add(addindex, temp[i]);
                    addindex++;
                }
            }
            temp=null;
        }
        else{
            b.setText("+");
            listTask.get(index).isAbierto =false;
            int removeindex=index+1;
            for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                if(listTask.get(removeindex).isAbierto){
                    removeChilds(removeindex);
                }
                listTask.remove(removeindex);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
public void removeChilds(int index){
    try {
        int removeindex=index+1;
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            if(listTask.get(removeindex).isAbierto){
                removeChilds(removeindex);
            }
            listTask.remove(removeindex);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception

    }
}
```

Fragment class.. the application crashes

public class TaskFragment extends Fragment {

```
TareaAdapter adapter;
ListView lvTask;
ArrayList<Task> listTask;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    lvTask =(ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lvTareas);
    lvTask.setDividerHeight(1);
    listTask =new ArrayList<Task>();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View viewRoot =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tareas, container, false);
    Button btnExpandir = (Button) viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.btnExpandirTarea);
    btnExpandir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CellButtonClick(v);
        }
    });
    return viewRoot;
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    if(listTask.size()==0){
        populateList();
    }
    super.onResume();
}

public Task getTask(int level, int haschild){
    Task task =new Task();
    task.nombre ="Nombre Tarea";
    task.isAbierto =false;
    task.nivel =level;
    task.tieneHijo = haschild;
    return task;
}
public void populateList()
{
    try
    {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            listTask.add(getTask(0, 1));
        }
        adapter = new TareaAdapter(getActivity(), listTask);
        lvTask.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
public void CellButtonClick(View v){
    try{
        Button b=(Button)v;
        int index;
        index=(Integer) b.getTag();

        if(b.getText().toString().equals("+")){
            b.setText("-");
            Task temp[]=new Task[2];
            int PLevel= listTask.get(index).nivel +1;
            for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                temp[i]= getTask(PLevel, 1);
            }
            listTask.get(index).isAbierto =true;
            if(temp!=null){
                int addindex=index+1;
                for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
                    listTask.add(addindex, temp[i]);
                    addindex++;
                }
            }
            temp=null;
        }
        else{
            b.setText("+");
            listTask.get(index).isAbierto =false;
            int removeindex=index+1;
            for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                if(listTask.get(removeindex).isAbierto){
                    removeChilds(removeindex);
                }
                listTask.remove(removeindex);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
public void removeChilds(int index){
    try {
        int removeindex=index+1;
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            if(listTask.get(removeindex).isAbierto){
                removeChilds(removeindex);
            }
            listTask.remove(removeindex);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put these three lines in `onCreateView` (and remove corresponding lines in `onActivityCreated`)

```
lvTask =(ListView) viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.lvTareas);
lvTask.setDividerHeight(1);
listTask =new ArrayList<Task>();
```

Comment: thanks for answering!.When I put those three lines in onCreateView, the application crashes. But, as I have, the fragment is shown and crashes by clicking

Comment: Post your log cat for the new crash.

Comment: I was wrong, now if it shows no problems. But I can not click and display the information.
When I run the application displays this error


`E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method CellButtonClick(View) in the activity class ....Inicio for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btnExpandirTarea'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3026)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)`

Comment: Your method definition for CellButtonClick(View) isn't defined in this inner class.  You could extend the OnClickListener class and add the definition, or just put the logic of CellButtonClick into the onClick method.